# Name spaces in C

Tags: c, namespaces, c99

I have the following code:

```
typedef struct Y {int X;} X;
enum E {X};
```

which generates a error:

> error: 'X' redeclared as different kind of symbol

As I know, C has implicitly defined namespaces for structure, union, and enum tags and also for their members. So, I'm not sure why does `E::X` collide with typedef structure tag `X`?

What exactly are name spaces in C?

Comment: maybe know how typedef define the X could help !, check if `enum E {Y};` or `enum E {int};` makes that error or not!,or maybe the `enum` structure doesn't create scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C does not have a separate namespace for `enum` members. When you write `enum {X}`, that creates a global constant `X` (which can clash with other global names such as `typedef`'d tags).

Comment: Ah, you're right. Only structure and union members have namespace.

Comment: @user963241: There are actually two other namespaces in C.  (1) Struct and union tags, such `tag` in `struct tag`.  (2) Labels.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: For example: `struct S {}; int S;` declared at global namespace so the `tag` doesn't clash with object `S`, right?

Comment: @user963241: Right, that's fine in C, except for the empty struct definition.

Answer (score 0):

Because the type `X` is declared in the *global* namespace, that then contains `enum E`, that, in turn, contains a redeclaration of `X`. So this happens because they're not on the same level - one "namespace" contains the other.